Use of 何 in constructs like 何者にもなれない
This recent answer reminded me of a quote from the anime Mawaru Penguindrum:

きっと何者にもなれないお前たち。
You who are surely unable to become somebody (literal TL)

Is there any significant difference between this and きっと誰にもなれないお前たち?
I'm trying to get a better feel for how 何 works in these kind of constructs. Grammatically, what things can I put 何 in front of?
I'm guessing it works with counter words. For example could I make something like 何{なん}時{じ}にもよくない for "it's not good at any hour"?
I'm not sure if 者 actually works as a counter though. What about adding 何 to nouns in general?

You're off track here since 何者 is a word unto itself and not prefix 何 + 者

何者【なにもの】 has more in common with 裏切【うらぎ】り者【もの】 or 化【ば】け物【もの】 than it does with 何人.

何者” in “何者にもなれない” carries the nuance of being a person who has achieved something, or sometimes someone socially important or recognized.

きっと何者にもなれないお前たち。
You guys who surely never become anyone of significance.

